# Is there any way to do change the look of slider ? move slider at different positions with image change

Tags: ios, iphone

hi this is an image i attached. Actually i want to build a system in which i want to move the car button (showing in image) to different specified positions(showing on the right) and at each position i want to replace the car image with different one(like truck, train). is there any way to do this ?

Link to the image:- 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-TGzvOW0sr9Wlk3T25DYWZlOGs/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is always a way to do it :-)

so create a UIView subclass which has two UIImageViews. 1st UIImageView can be the horizontal line. and the second UIImageView can be the with the car. you then move the UIImageView horizontally as you wish and set different images while changing the position.

edit:
1. moving an UI element can be done with resetting the frame of UI element.
for example if an image was at position (x,y, width, height) and you want to move 20 points to the right then it will be (x + 20, y, width, height)

2. if you use auto layout then you can just change the constant of your x-constraint in this case.

edit 2 :
you can use (Tap/Pan) Gesture recogniser. you will get the exact position and as well as the velocity with different state (gesture started/ended/changed).

Comment: Hi thanks for the instant responce, i totally understand the method and the way you told. kindly explain a little bit more about :- 
=>"you then then move the UIImageView horizontally as you wish and set different images while changing the position."<=

Comment: thanks alot for elaborating the point, it helps alot in understanding the concept and really helped. it helped me in clearing my task. ----As this is the concept done manually means by code only.........=>"what it we have to give this privilege to user so that user can slide the car icon from one position to another and image of icon change immediately. is it possible to do this too"<=